# Hiding command prompt when using python

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

Is there a way to hide the windows command prompt or prevent it from popping up every time I us a command with python? My program loops command prompt commands causing my screen to flash with prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) or [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) with `shell=True` as an argument. Here is an example with Popen

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('pwd', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> output = p.stdout.read()
>>> print output
C:\Python27
```